# What is the distribution of the product of three random variables?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_of_the_product_of_two_random_variables#Derivation_for_independent_random_variables): If $X$ and $Y$ are two independent, continuous random variables, described by probability density functions $f_{X}$ and $f_{Y}$ then the probability density function of $Z=XY$ is

\begin{equation}
f_{Z}(z)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_{X}(x)f_{Y}(z/x)\frac{1}{|x|}dx
\end{equation}

Suppose now that we have another independent, continuous random variable $W$, described by probability density function $f_{W}$, what is the probability density function of $Z=XYW$?

Is the following expression correct
\begin{equation}
f_{Z}(z)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_{X}(x)f_{Y}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)f_{W}\left(\frac{z}{y}\right)\frac{1}{|xy|}dxdy
\end{equation}?

Comment: Hint: use $Z=VW$ with $V:=XY$ to apply what you already know repeatedly. You should find a result dimensional analysis might have led you to conjecture,$$f_{Z}\left(z\right)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_{X}\left(x\right)f_{Y}\left(y\right)f_{W}\left(\frac{z}{xy}\right)\frac{1}{\left|xy\right|}dxdy.$$

Comment: @J.G., for independent variables, is the pdf for $XY$ equal to $YX$ always?

Comment: If you're asking whether those products have the same PDF, bear in mind they're equal.

Comment: @J.G., isn't the correct p.d.f \begin{equation}
f_{Z}(z)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_{X}(x)f_{Y}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)f_{W}\left(\frac{z}{y}\right)\frac{1}{|xy|}dxdy
\end{equation}?

Comment: Only if you use $y$, not say $v$, to label the value of $V$. Note that $dv/|v|=dy/|y|$.

Comment: @J.G., not sure what you mean could you please explain more.

Comment: @J.G. is my p.d.f correct?

Comment: The two PDFs are the same, but mine would be less confusing as it calls $Y$'s value $y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, just apply the definition twice:

$$f_{XYW}(z)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_{XY}(t)f_W\left(\dfrac zt\right)\dfrac1{|t|}dt=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_X(x)f_Y\left(\dfrac tx\right)\dfrac1{|x|}dxf_W\left(\dfrac zt\right)\dfrac1{|t|}dt$$
Or, by Fubini or Tonelli's theorem,
$$f_{XYW}(z)=\int_{\Bbb R^2}f_X(x)f_Y\left(\dfrac tx\right)f_W\left(\dfrac zt\right)\dfrac{dtdx}{|tx|}$$

Comment: is $\int_{\Bbb R^2}$ the same as $\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty$?